# Variable Frequency Drives for slowing down a motor

Tags: vfd

I am changing my water pump over form a diesel engine to electric motor. Problem is the motor i have is too fast, and it will be complicated to replace it.

The pump requires more power the faster it turns. I have a 4 kW motor that spins at 2880 RPM @ 50 Hz. My pump wants more like 1750 rpm.

I used pulleys  of different sizes and have got the ratio I want, and got the pump working as required with this motor.  BUT I want to directly couple the motor to the pump.  Belts have been a thorn in my side for years and I just can't go on with them. I also would benefit from being able to fine tune the RPM to get optimum output from the pump in different situations. Much like I was able to do with the diesel.

So I thought that a VFD would be a good solution. I lack any experience with them, so I have read and watch a bunch and fell like I get the concept. However I want to make sure that I don't make another mistake.

Can a VFD slow down my motor that much and still have good power?

Or maybe a better question is:

Is a VFD the right thing for me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is is a 3 phase ac motor? Any link to it?

Comment: yes 3 phase ac motor

Comment: Due to the drop in available power from a VFD as mentioned below, I would go with a pulley.

Comment: It would be very helpful to know how much mechanical power or torque the pump needs at 1750 RPM. Or maybe if you know the power rating of the diesel motor at 1800 RPM (maybe just the make and model of diesel). This will help us determine if the existing electric motor can be used with a VFD.

Comment: @winny that was the concept I was concerned about.  can you elaborate "drop in available power?"  The slow the motor goes the less power it has?????

Comment: @ mkeith I will add a photo of the pump specs, the diesel is a yanmar 155

Comment: A good quality vfd will probably be as expensive as the motor. I’d lean towards using a belt, chain or gears as it will be cheaper than a vfd in the long run.

Comment: Yes, as explained in the answers below, to slow down the motor but keeping the current same, you have less power (and less fan cooling available). The VFD itself doesn’t steal or burn the power, it’s just the consequence of using a VFD to run a motor slower.

Comment: What comment is that? ;) ;)  It's gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VFD can run the motor at 1800 RPM. That is no problem. But the rated motor output power scales with the RPM. So you will not have 4 kW mechanical power available. Or not safely.

If you can deliver 4 kW at 2880, then you can safely use 1800/2880 * 4 = 2.5 kW at 1800 RPM. So if your load only needs 2.5 kW of shaft power at 1800 RPM then it should be OK. If you need the full 4 kW at 1800 RPM, you will have to overload the motor. While this is possible (an oversized VFD can make the motor put out 4 kW at 1800 RPM), it may cause the motor to overheat or fail prematurely.

Also, not all motors can be run at reduced speed. Some have cooling fans on the shaft. The cooling airflow is reduced at low speed but the internal heat generation is NOT reduced (depends only on torque). If the motor has a built-in fan, then you may want to add additional ventilation with an external fan to make sure it doesn't run hot.

I have personally run induction motors at double torque and double power using VFDs. They can do it. But in my application the motor doesn't run very often and it was very cheap and it is easy to replace so I don't worry about it. In an application where the motor runs continuously and is difficult to replace, I would suggest that you operate within the nameplate limits.

I found a catalog for yuema motors [here](http://www.yuemadrive.com/downloads/brosur-yuema-motor-yu-&-sa.pdf).

In the catalog or brochure they mention that 50 Hz motors may be run at 60 Hz, so it is safe to overspeed the motor. The motor you have now is a 2 pole motor (3000 RPM synchronous speed at 50 Hz). There is a 4 pole version of the same motor (1500 RPM synchronous speed at 50 Hz). It seems like the 4 pole version would be a good fit for your application, and it is safe to run it with a VFD at 60 Hz (which will give you around 1750 RPM at full load).

The model number is SA-112M-4.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I have my answer... which is a VFD won't get me out of this jam.  Could I ask you, if I was to start from scratch, and I want to get the 1750 RPM requiring 3.7 kw of power (as per the above table for the pump i have) and it must be coupled to the motor, so no belts, would you recommend a VFD and a faster or slower motor, and what size?

Comment: I live in the US. For us the correct motor would be a 5HP (3750 Watts) 1800 RPM motor. I am not sure if this is a normal size where you live. Maybe it is 4 kW? Also, most induction motors (aka asynchronous motors) can be run a bit faster than their rated speed at full power. So if you can find a motor rated for 4 kW at 1450 RPM you can probably use it safely at 1750 RPM with a VFD. Ideally you would be able to find this information from the manufacturer for confirmation.

Comment: Probably the 4-pole version of that same motor. The SA-112M-4. http://www.yuemadrive.com/downloads/brosur-yuema-motor-yu-&-sa.pdf

Answer (score 3):

> Can a VFD slow down my motor that much and still have good power?

It depends what you mean by 'good'. If you mean 4 kW, then no. If you mean 'sufficient for your pump at lower speed', then maybe yes.

Slowing an AC motor down also means the voltage has to drop, maximum applied voltage is proportional to motor speed, which a VFD should do quite happily.

The torque from the motor depends on the current. At lower speed, the motor cooling might be compromised, if cooling is done with a shaft-mounted fan. With less cooling, you won't be able to use as much current without overheating. A motor of that size however may have a separate fan motor or at least air-path that can be used to maintain full speed cooling.

Characterise the power or torque that your pump needs to turn it at your target speed. You may be able to estimate this very roughly by the power consumption of your motor driving the pump at your target speed through belts.

Answer (score 2):

**Using a VFD for speed control of an induction motor**

The characteristic curves are as shown below.

[image]

**Up to the rated speed:**

The ratio of voltage to frequency is a constant (V / f = k) with the power increasing linearly and the torque remaining constant at its rated value.

The lowered cooling effect of the in-built fan, at lower than rated speed, is not an issue as the power and consequent heating is lower.

**Above the rated speed:**

The voltage, and hence power, is constant at the rated value and the torque decreases.

**Using a belt and pulleys to reduce the speed of the 4 kW motor from 2880 RPM to 1750 RPM:**

At the lowered speed, with the power remaining at 4 kW, there is a torque increase to the extent of 65 % of the rated torque.

**Conclusion:**

At 1750 RPM, only the rated torque is available using a VFD against an additional 65% of the rated torque using a belt and pulleys.

You need to check whether the motor rated torque is sufficient to drive the pump.

Answer (score 1):

Another consideration is that the belt drive will be absorbing some power, more efficient to run direct drive.
The pump data shows 2.2kw required at 1450 RPM. This would imply that a 2.2kw inverter drive would be sufficient. Running the motor at 25Hz should give you about 1400 RPM.

Also, if necessary, you could get an inverter which runs from a single phase 220v supply.
This would give you 3 phase output at 220v phase-to-phase. The motor you have can be wired in 'Delta' configuration to run from this.

Some inverter manufacturers supply drives specifically for running pumps and fans which utilise hall-effect feedback sensors, and actively reduce the voltage to the motor whilst maintaining frequency/speed, once the pump or fan is up and running. This can result in significant energy savings